# Use Activity's toolbar to Navigate up from Fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, toolbar

In my app, MainActivity uses a navigation drawer to host several fragments. MainActivity provides the toolbar, and fragment content is displayed beneath the toolbar in a Frame Layout.

In MainActivity, I start my first fragment and initialize my toolbar as shown below.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment 1");
```

One of my fragments needs a subfragment. I would like to add a back button to that subfragment, and override onBackPressed() within MainActivity.

My toolbar currently only shows the 3-line hamburger, which when pressed opens Navigation Drawer and shows a list of my fragments.

I'm not sure how to show a back arrow in my subfragment instead of a hamburger. Then I need to catch the onBackPressed() event and handle it.

I may be doing this incorrectly, and might should use activities instead of fragments, but if I do, I won't be able to animate fragment slide_in / slide_out transitions. The toolbar would slide along with the Frame Layout and I don't want that.

I would like the fragment content to show a transition, while the toolbar remains in place. Just as you would expect in a View Pager.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your "home icon" calling those lines:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_arrow_icon);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

For handling the "home click" your must override the onOptionsItemSelected and handle the click listener for the home MenuItem (android.R.id.home).

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Good luck!